# How do I get the index of selected row in Tkinter Treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I want to get the index of the row that I selected in Tkinter Treeview. Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: have you tried `tree.index(tree.selection())`?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way.  But to do this, I created two lists.  . The first was the selected value/s. The second was the list of the entire treeview.  Then by iterating through the second list, incrementing each iteration, with a simple if statment you can find the index.

This is a sample of my code

```
selected =my_tree.focus()
values=list(my_tree.item(selected,'values'))
all_records = []
for child in my_tree.get_children():
    all_records.append([my_tree.item(child)["values"][0],str(my_tree.item(child)["values"][1]),str(my_tree.item(child)["values"][2]),my_tree.item(child)["values"][3],my_tree.item(child)["values"][4],str(my_tree.item(child)["values"][5]),str(my_tree.item(child)["values"][6])])
index=0
for record in all_records:
    if record ==values:
        print(index)
    index+=1
```